# React-Boilerplate run production without port

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, deployment, react-boilerplate

Well, I want to deploy the [react-boilerplate](https://github.com/react-boilerplate/react-boilerplate) project to my digital ocean vps server.
Command `npm run start:production` runs the application by address `http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:3000/`.

I'm going to run the server without port like `http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX` or `http://my-domain.com`.

How can I set port or domain for production mode?

Comment: Make an iptable map to 80 or 8080

Comment: Yes, How can I change the port in `react-boilerplate`? I think there should be a simple command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally you will run your node app on localhost at port 3000. Then you would use nginx as a proxy to receive connections on port 80/443 and forward them to your server running on port 3000. Here are some notes that describe some of the configuration needed for this:

https://github.com/jensen/deployment-notes#nginx

Answer (score 1):

Try using `PORT=80 npm run start:production` if you will use http or `PORT=443 npm run start:production` if you will use https. That should make your app accessible without a port on digital ocean.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, it works properly only with `npm start`

Comment: For production you can do the following: `PORT=80 npm run start:production`

Comment: Yup, this works!. How can I set domain name instead of ip address?

Comment: This part is not related to react-boilerplate. You need to get a domain and set up the DNS to point to the IP address.

Comment: If this answer helped you resolve the problem, I'd appreciate if you mark it as the correct answer. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, it solved the problem but I'm still wondering if it is safe and good approach to use Port 80.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest, Serve build file using file server.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-do-i-put-up-a-simple-static-website